# Ingest video by Edge connector Kinesis video streams or ProducerSDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot-core, aws-iot-greengrass, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I want to ingest videos and datas from IoTCar. I will install greengrass core to car's edge gateway. According to aws docs, I found two ways to deal with this.
 
1, Using stream manager to ingest data and export to kinesis data streams; Using edge connector kinesis video streams to put video to kinesis video streams.

2,Install kinesis video streams produer sdk or call api directly without installing sdk, and then put videos to kinesis video streams, and send data to IoTCore with MQTT without stream manager.
 
It seems that Method 1 is much simpler than Method 2. But I can't find detail docs about Method 1 by google. I found more details about Method 2.
Can you tell me which method is better? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to handle this,

1. Stream video Using your first option - [a link](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp) . And send other data via MQTT (you can use AWS MQTT service as well other)
2. Use Producer SDK for video streaming, and send your other data as metadata(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/how-meta.html. And you can consume this metadata in your consumer. For python, you can use (https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-consumer-library-for-python) Using this you can extract metadata as well as frames.